# In Excel, how can I apply a complex formula expressed as equations in many cells to the data in each row of a table automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I spent many hours making a spreadsheet that takes in a dozen variables and a dozen constants, uses equations in many cells to generate intermediate values, and combines these using a final equation to generate a final answer. Call this sheet "The Machine".

Now I need to apply all this same math to a table of about fifty rows that each contain different values for the dozen input variables. I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Manually copy the input variables to where The Machine expects them to be, look in The Machine's output cell, and copy its value to the appropriate cell in the row. Repeat this laboriously fifty times. Do it all again if the input table changes.
2. Recreate The Machine on one row, off to the right of the first row of my table, taking the dozen inputs from where they are on row one of the table. Then flash fill that one-row machine down all fifty rows.

I really don't like either option. The reason is obvious for 1). For 2), the reason is that "The Machine" is now far harder to understand, it doesn't have my cells that contain descriptions, and it's fragile in the sense that if I change it on one row I have to remember to copy the change fifty times. If I keep the original Machine in its own sheet and also have the flatten one-row version, I now have another way for them to get out of sync.

So, what's the best solution to this problem? Is there a way to encapsulate a set of equations as a user-defined function or some such, give it a name, and refer to it easily from each table row? Anything else? I guess I want something like a VBA macro, but it would be really dumb to have to reimplement The Machine in code after I've already implemented it in Excel. Also, I've never used VBA.

Comment: A dozen variables is too many (a dozen constants are not a problem - they are part of the Machine, right?). Unfortunately, [**the mechanism that Excel offers**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-e95e2487-6ca6-4413-ad12-77542a5ea50b) works with one or two input variables. But you can add (for example) a row number (index) to the source data table, and start calculations in the Machine by getting values from the next row (send row number to Machine as a single parameter). Try it, I'm sure you will most likely succeed.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to create a macro that FOR EACH row will copy from your input/output sheet to the relevant cells in your machine, then copy the result back to your input/output sheet.

Comment: Absolutely, create a named formula using a Lambda.  Then  you just call the named function and include the range(s)) in brackets.  It could even automatically apply to all rows that are populated. If you edit your question with a minimal reproducible example of the machine (just minimal prototype) we'll  provide an example formula you can adapt to the actual machine. If you want to keep the various formulas intact, you can name each one & then have another named formula that calls them.  At the end , you'd have a named formula that you just provide the required range(s) of values to.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The lambda idea has the outcome that I'm looking for, but if I understand right, it requires me to reimplement my machine as a super long single line of code, right? I can't point the lambda at the existing implementation of a bunch of cells connected to each other with portions of the full equation residing in each cell?

Comment: @gns100 This sounds promising. I don't know how to do this. If you give an example in an answer I will mark it best answer, given that the other two comments don't quite satisfy the need.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any VBA on hand that would be a good example. However, there are a bunch of stuff on the web, just start with individual blocks. First write a marco that copies the result from the machine to the output section, Next add on the part that copies from the input to the machine. Finally wrap a loop around that. Obviously, there are nuances for you to figure out. Good luck.

Comment: If you never wrote vba, start with a basic "hello world" tutorial. I also started with  the macro builder that gives me hard coded results, that I then generalize to variables,.